# is there any possibility in Cypress to intercept and modify request body?

Tags: cypress

I need to mock some data and overwrite request body made by FE to API.
So I am clicking some button and would like to replace POST request body with something mocked, for example from a file.

I know we can modify responses with intercepts, but this is not the case I want.

Answer (score 3):

[cy.intercept allows you to control the outbound request.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Controlling-the-outbound-request-with-req-continue) The following example is mostly from the link.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/submitStory', (req) => {
  req.body.storyName = 'some name';
  // send the modified request and skip any other
  // matching request handlers
  req.continue(res => {
    res.body = 'new res body'
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To intercept and provide the complete POST request body:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/employees', (req) => {
    req.body = {"name":"alex","email":"alex@ca.com","phone":349811}
    }).as('interceptedPost');
```